# plot of 3 competing species with diffusion

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make a code for a model of competing three species with diffusion to get plots (  2d plot u, v, w against time ) My model is

```
u'=d1u_xx+(r1-a1u-b1v-c1w)u
v'=d2v_xx+(r2-a2u-b2v-c2w)v
w'=d3w_xx+(r3-a3u-b3v-c3w)w
where d1=d2=d3=1;
r1=1.5; r2=2.65; r3=3.45;
a1=0.1; b1=0.3; c1=0.01; b2=0.2;
a2=0.3; c2=0.2; c3=0.2; a3=0.01; b3=0.1.
```

I did the code for this model without diffusion as follow

```
% Define diff. equations, time span and initial conditions, e.g.
tspan = [0 20];
y0 = [0.2 0.2 0.2];

r1=1.5;     r2=2.65;    r3=3.45;
a1=0.1;     a2=0.3;     a3=0.01; 
b1=0.3;     b2=0.2;     b3=0.1;
c1=0.01;    c2=0.2;     c3=0.2; 

dy = @(t,y) [
(r1-a1*y(1)-b1*y(2)-c1*y(3))*y(1);
(r2-a2*y(1)-b2*y(2)-c2*y(3))*y(2);
(r3-a3*y(1)-b3*y(2)-c3*y(3))*y(3)];

% Solve differential equations
[t,y] = ode45(dy, tspan, y0);
 % Plot all species against time
figure(1)
plot(t,y)
```

Resulting in following figure:

[image]

how to do it with diffusion like in  [this paper](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1372180511) figure 10u, v, w

Comment: Could you post here the figure you are trying to prepare? Also a legend what does each line represent would be helpful too.

Comment: this figure you have plotted without diffusion, each line represent the species u,v,w. about what i want is to plot these equations with diffusion same initial value and  the boundary condition is (r1/a1, 0, 0) . I put the paper that study similar thing, so i want like in figure 10

Comment: this is the paper [link](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1372180511)